# Calling cin.get() twice: unexpected result?

Tags: c++, cin

So I was playing around with cin.get() to try and understand it more thoroughly.

```
char x[20];
cout << "Enter a name: ";
cin >> x;
cout << cin.get();
```

If I enter "Bob Smith", it outputs 32 - the ASCII number for space - which I expected as it's the character after the input stream.

```
char x[20];
cout << "Enter a name: ";
cin >> x;
cout << cin.get() << " " << cin.get()
```

However, this outputs "83 32", which confuses me. Why does it reverse the order to output "S" before space?

Answer (score 2):

If you change `cout << cin.get() << " " << cin.get()` to the following code:

```
cout << cin.get();
cout << " " << cin.get();
```

It prints `32 83`, which is not reversed.

This is because if you put two conditions in one line, C++ might not evaluate them in order.